# Conversión de arrays php

Tags: php, php7

Tengo un Array con esta estructura

```
 3 => {#631 ▼
      +"id": 20
      +"cliente": "Juan Pérez"
      +"codigo": "01/A2"
    }
    4 => {#1038 ▼
      +"id": 20
      +"cliente": "Juan Pérez"
      +"codigo": "01/A3"
    }
    5 => {#1249 ▼
      +"id": 20
      +"cliente": "Juan Pérez"
      +"codigo": "01/A1"
    }
    6 => {#1248 ▼
      +"id": 19
      +"cliente": "Autoescuelas Perez S.L"
      +"codigo": "01/A3"
    }
    7 => {#1251 ▼
      +"id": 19
      +"cliente": "Autoescuelas Perez S.L"
      +"codigo": "01/A1"
    }
    8 => {#1252 ▼
      +"id": 19
      +"cliente": "Autoescuelas Perez S.L"
      +"codigo": "01/A2"
    }
    9 => {#1253 ▼
      +"id": 18
      +"cliente": "bfsfdgsdfg"
      +"codigo": "01/A2"
    }
```

Necesito transformarlo en esto:

```
 3 => {#631 ▼
      +"id": 20
      +"cliente": "Juan Pérez"
      +"codigo": "01/A2,01/A3,01/A1"
    }
6 => {#1248 ▼
      +"id": 19
      +"cliente": "Autoescuelas Perez S.L"
      +"codigo": "01/A2,01/A3,01/A1"
    }
 9 => {#1253 ▼
      +"id": 18
      +"cliente": "bfsfdgsdfg"
      +"codigo": "01/A2"
    }
```

He probado varias cosas pero ninguna funciono medianamente bien o llego a funcionar, es mas no se ni como plantearlo la verdad porque si haces un bucle a igual id y extraes la parte de codigo, usar el operador + para juntar los dos codigos no me funciono así que no se como tratar con esto la verdad.
he intenado esto:

```
 $ite=0;
        for ($i=0; $i <count($ventas) ; $i++) {
            if ($ite < count($ventas)-1) {
                $ite++;
            }
            if ($ventas[$i]->id==$ventas[$ite]->id) {
                $ventas[$i]->codigo=$ventas[$i]->codigo." ".$ventas[$ite]->codigo;
                
            }
        }
```

Pero no se acerca ni remotamente a lo que necesito

Comment: Y que as intentando? Las preguntas que buscan ayudan deben incluir un ejemplo minimo de lo que se a intentado!

Comment: Mas bien para obtener esos indices 3,6 y 9, primero ordenalos que lleven el orden del numero inicial 1,2,3,4,5 vaya que sean consecutivos, despues como los numeros que buscas son impares, pones un if que verifique si es par lo salte y si es impar que guarde los datos en otro array, para al final usar este ultimo array para lo que necesitas

Comment: Lo otro que tambien puedes hacer es verificar que el id que hayas pasado, no se igual al primero y si lo es que lo omita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer agrupaciones fácilmente si usas el agrupador (id del cliente) como llave de un arreglo. Lo importante es verificar la existencia de la llave para decidir entre inicializar o agregar:

```
$nuevo = [];
foreach( $ventas as $i => &$x )
   if( !isset($nuevo[$x->id]) ){  // ¿Primera vez que se procesa el id?
      $x->codigos = [$x->codigo]; // Inicializa un arreglo de códigos
      unset( $x->codigo );        
      $x->primerId = $i;          // Temporalmente la llave final
      $nuevo[$x->id] = $x;
   }else                                      // Cliente ya procesado
      $nuevo[$x->id]->codigos[] = $x->codigo; // Sólo agregar código
```

Aquí la recomendación es manejar los códigos como un arreglo en lugar de una lista separada por comas. En caso de requerirlo, en cualquier momento es fácil hacer `implode(',', $ventas[6]->codigos)`.

Un ejemplo del resultado para el cliente 20 sería:

```
    [20] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 20
            [cliente] => Juan Pérez
            [codigos] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 01/A2
                    [1] => 01/A3
                    [2] => 01/A1
                )
            [primerId] => 3
        )
```

Si la llave original (`primerId`) es desechable no es necesario el código siguiente para reasignar:

```
// Cambiar por la llave inicial
foreach( $nuevo as $key => $val ){
   $id = $val->primerId;
   unset( $val->primerId, $nuevo[$key] );
   $nuevo[$id] = $val;
}
```

El resultado final deberá ser algo así:

```
Array
(
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 20
            [cliente] => Juan Pérez
            [codigos] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 01/A2
                    [1] => 01/A3
                    [2] => 01/A1
                )
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 19
            [cliente] => Autoescuelas Perez S.L
            [codigos] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 01/A3
                    [1] => 01/A1
                    [2] => 01/A2
                )
        )

    [9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 18
            [cliente] => bfsfdgsdfg
            [codigos] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 01/A2
                )
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurren 3 maneras para resolverlo:

1.- Detectar los impares mediante un if

2.- Crear un if que vaya guardando los ids, y compararlos en cada vuelta y validar que sea diferente a

3.- En tu consulta ordena con un ORDER BY ID ASC/DESC y agregale un DISTINCT id para que ordene los valores y remueva tus duplicados

Este seria un ejemplo ya que no se como es tu estructura completa, simule los valores para obtener los impares

https://paiza.io/projects/LeuyO6y_dcGFLzP8JbDBlg

```
<?php
// Your code here!
    $array = [
       3 => [
            "id"=> 20,
            "cliente"=> "Juan Pérez",
            "codigo"=>"01/A2"
           ],
        4 => [
            "id"=> 20,
            "cliente"=> "Juan Pérez",
            "codigo"=>"01/A2"
           ],
        5 => [
            "id"=> 20,
            "cliente"=> "Juan Pérez",
            "codigo"=>"01/A2"
           ],
        6 => [
            "id"=> 19,
            "cliente"=> "Autoescuelas Perez S.L",
            "codigo"=>"01/A2"
           ],
        7 => [
            "id"=> 19,
            "cliente"=> "Autoescuelas Perez S.L",
            "codigo"=>"01/A3"
           ],
        8 => [
            "id"=> 19,
            "cliente"=> "Autoescuelas Perez S.L",
            "codigo"=>"01/A3"
           ],
        9 => [
            "id"=> 18,
            "cliente"=> "Juan Pérez",
            "codigo"=>"01/A2"
           ],
    ];
    
    
    $success = [];
    $index = 3;
    
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
    {
        if (($index % 2) != 0) 
        {
            $success[] = $array[$index];
        }
        $index++;
    }
    
    unset($success[0]);
    var_dump($success);
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo mas recomendable es usar el DISTINCT ya que es más fácil, sino lo siguiente es crear el if y tomar los ids unicos evitando los duplicados, para mantener la consistencia de los datos, y la parte de los impares puede variar, tendrias que analizar si en tus impares puedan venir mas duplicados no es muy recomendable, pero analiza y trata de adaptar cualquiera de estas soluciones